# Build array of 2 arrays using JAVASCRIPT REDUCE with one line using Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of objects

```
const companyList = [
    {
        name: 'amazon',
        isIntermediary: false
    },
    {
        name: 'microsoft',
        isIntermediary: false
    },
    {
        name: 'talentsearch',
        isIntermediary: true
    },
    {
        name: 'talent global',
        isIntermediary: true
    },
    {
        name: 'taleo',
        isIntermediary: true
    }
];
```

I want to create 2 arrays. I can do so using reduce

```
const companies = companyList.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => {
        if (!curr.isIntermediary) {
            acc[0].push(curr);
        } else {
            acc[1].push(curr);
        }
        return acc;
    },
    [[], []]
);
```

Is there a way to refactor this code to use Ternary Operator instead and have it being a one-liner? I'm struggling to do so... Thanks for help !

Comment: what is the expected outpur??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean converted to Number becomes 0 or 1, and [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) can be used to shorten it :

```js
const companyList = [ { name: 'amazon',        isIntermediary: false },
                      { name: 'microsoft',     isIntermediary: false },
                      { name: 'talentsearch',  isIntermediary: true  },
                      { name: 'talent global', isIntermediary: true  },
                      { name: 'taleo',         isIntermediary: true  } ]
                      
const companies = companyList.reduce((a, v) => (a[+v.isIntermediary].push(v), a), [[], []])

console.log(companies)
```

Comment: That's what's up! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By your code, this is what you want (using ternary to choose whether index `0` or `1`)

```js
const companyList = [
    {
        name: 'amazon',
        isIntermediary: false
    },
    {
        name: 'microsoft',
        isIntermediary: false
    },
    {
        name: 'talentsearch',
        isIntermediary: true
    },
    {
        name: 'talent global',
        isIntermediary: true
    },
    {
        name: 'taleo',
        isIntermediary: true
    }
];

const companies = companyList.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => [!curr.isIntermediary ? [...acc[0], curr] : [...acc[0]], curr.isIntermediary ? [...acc[1], curr] : [...acc[1]]],
    [[], []]
);

console.log(companies)
```

Comment: I wanna do a one liner i.e. no curly braces and return

Comment: Edited, try now

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the most readable one-liner, but I think it's what you've asked for.

```js
const companyList = [{
    name: 'amazon',
    isIntermediary: false
  },
  {
    name: 'microsoft',
    isIntermediary: false
  },
  {
    name: 'talentsearch',
    isIntermediary: true
  },
  {
    name: 'talent global',
    isIntermediary: true
  },
  {
    name: 'taleo',
    isIntermediary: true
  }
];

const companies = companyList.reduce((acc, c) => c.isIntermediary ? [acc[0], [...acc[1], c]] : [[...acc[0], c], acc[1]], [[], []]);

console.log(companies)
```